# When I try to create a table in MySQL, it gives me error code 1215: “Cannot add foreign key constraint”

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a database, but when I run this code, I get this error:

> Code 1215: “Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Code:

```
drop database if exists kat_db;

create database if not exists kat_db;

use kat_db;

create table if not exists Patients
(
    PatientID int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    PatientName varchar(50),
    TypeOfAnimal varchar(50),
    DateOfLastApt date,
    PatientAge int,
    Microchipped boolean,
    OwnerID int not null,
    DoctorID int not null,

    foreign key (OwnerID) references Owners(OwnerID),
    foreign key (DoctorID) references Doctors(DoctorID)
);

create table if not exists Owners
(
    OwnerID int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    OwnerFirstName varchar(50),
    OwnerLastName varchar(50),
    PatientID int,
    OwnerPhone int,
    OwnerZip int,
    PreferredPaymentMethod varchar(50),

    foreign key (PatientID) references Patients(PatientID)
);

create table if not exists Doctors
(
    DoctorID int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    DoctorFirstName varchar(50),
    DoctorLastName varchar(50),
    PatientID int,
    DoctorPhone int,
    DoctorZip int,
    AnimalSpecialty varchar(50),

    foreign key (PatientID) references Patients(PatientID)
);

insert into Patients (PatientID, TypeOfAnimal, PatientAge, PatientName, DateOfLastApt, Microchipped, DoctorID, OwnerID)
values (01, 'dog', 6, 'Dima', '2017-02-05', 1, 101, 1001),
       (02, 'dog', 3, 'Misha', '2017-02-05', 1, 102, 1002),
       (03, 'cat', 2, 'Pistol', '2017-06-09', 0, 103, 1003),
       (04, 'cat', 1, 'Nessie', '2017-09-04', 0, 104, 1004),
       (05, 'cat', 2, 'Charlie', '2016-06-04', 1, 105, 1005),
       (06, 'cat', 12, 'Francis', '2015-05-07', 1, 106, 1006),
       (07, 'rabbit', 5, 'Bunny', '2015-05-06', 0, 107, 1007),
       (08, 'turtle', 6, 'Aqua', '2017-06-08', 0, 108, 1008),
       (09, 'dog', 16, 'Sammie', '2012-09-07', 1, 109, 1009),
       (10, 'dog', 14, 'Dog', '2016-04-06', 0, 110, 1010);

insert into Owners (OwnerID, OwnerFirstName, OwnerLastName, OwnerPhone, OwnerZip, PreferredPaymentMethod, PatientID)
values (101, 'Kat', 6, 'Dima', '2017-02-05', 1, 101, 1001),
       (102, 'Hunter', 3, 'Misha', '2017-02-05', 1, 102, 1002),
       (103, 'Vicky', 2, 'Pistol', '2017-06-09', 0, 103, 1003),
       (104, 'Vanessa', 1, 'Nessie', '2017-09-04', 0, 104, 1004),
       (105, 'Weston', 2, 'Charlie', '2016-06-04', 1, 105, 1005),
       (106, 'Jonas', 12, 'Francis', '2015-05-07', 1, 106, 1006),
       (107, 'Devin', 5, 'Bunny', '2015-05-06', 0, 107, 1007),
       (108, 'Grego', 6, 'Aqua', '2017-06-08', 0, 108, 1008),
       (109, 'Jackson', 16, 'Sammie', '2012-09-07', 1, 109, 1009),
       (110, 'dog', 14, 'Dog', '2016-04-06', 0, 110, 1010);

insert into Patients (PatientID, TypeOfAnimal, PatientAge, PatientName, DateOfLastApt, Microchipped, DoctorID, OwnerID)
values (01, 'dog', 6, 'Dima', '2017-02-05', 1, 101, 1001),
       (02, 'dog', 3, 'Misha', '2017-02-05', 1, 102, 1002),
       (03, 'cat', 2, 'Pistol', '2017-06-09', 0, 103, 1003),
       (04, 'cat', 1, 'Nessie', '2017-09-04', 0, 104, 1004),
       (05, 'cat', 2, 'Charlie', '2016-06-04', 1, 105, 1005),
       (06, 'cat', 12, 'Francis', '2015-05-07', 1, 106, 1006),
       (07, 'rabbit', 5, 'Bunny', '2015-05-06', 0, 107, 1007),
       (08, 'turtle', 6, 'Aqua', '2017-06-08', 0, 108, 1008),
       (09, 'dog', 16, 'Sammie', '2012-09-07', 1, 109, 1009),
       (10, 'dog', 14, 'Dog', '2016-04-06', 0, 110, 1010);
```

I tried creating the tables in different order. I also created a different database, which worked, In fact, I used this to create the database on the top.

```
drop database if exists kat3_db;
create database if not exists kat3_db;
use kat3_db;
create table if not exists Book(
BookNumber int not null,
BookName varchar(50),
BookPrice decimal(5,2),
CoverType varchar(15) default 'hardcover',
PublicationDate date,
primary key (BookNumber)
);

create table if not exists Course(
CourseNo int not null,
CourseName varchar(20),
Semester varchar(10),
BookNumber int not null,
primary key (CourseNo),
foreign key (BookNumber) references Book(BookNumber)
);

insert into Book
(BookNumber, BookName, BookPrice, CoverType, PublicationDate)
values 
(1, 'Math', 023.64, 'paperback', '1999-02-05'),
(3, 'English', 999.36, 'e-book', '2013-06-04'),
(5, 'Calc', 056.69, 'paperback', '1964-05-05'),
(6, 'C++', 053.98, 'paperback', '2016-03-04'),
(7, 'Programming', 113.02, 'paperback', '2001-10-11'),
(9, 'Art', 250.99, 'paperback', '1996-11-11'),
(10, 'Networking', 036.64, 'e-book', '2014-05-06'),
(12, 'Drawing', 111.36, 'paperback', '2013-06-04'),
(13, 'Robotics', 012.03, 'e-book', '2016-06-05'),
(14, 'Computer', 25.03, 'e-book', '2001-06-04')
;

insert into Book
(BookNumber, BookName, BookPrice, PublicationDate)
values
(2, 'Reading', 364.20, '2016-06-05'),
(4, 'Database', 036.64, '2017-06-05'),
(8, 'Wellness', 050.00, '1999-10-10'),
(11, 'Linux', 55.36, '2013-06-08'),
(15, 'FYE', 03.01, '1991-02-05')
;

insert into Course
(CourseNo, CourseName, Semester, BookNumber)
values
(111, 'IntroToMath', 'Spring', 1),
(222, 'IntroToReading', 'Fall', 2),
(333, 'IntroToEnglish', 'Spring', 3),
(444, 'IntroToDatabase', 'Fall', 4),
(555, 'IntroToCalc', 'Spring', 5),
(666, 'IntroToC++', 'Spring', 6),
(777, 'IntroToProgramming', 'Fall', 7),
(888, 'IntroToWellness','Spring', 8),
(999, 'IntroToArt', 'Fall', 9),
(010, 'IntroToNetworking', 'Spring', 10),
(011, 'IntroToLinux', 'Fall', 11),
(012, 'IntroToDrawing', 'Spring', 12),
(013, 'IntroToRobotics', 'Fall', 13),
(014, 'IntroToComputer', 'Spring', 14),
(015, 'IntroToFYE', 'Summer', 15)
;
```

I do not see what I did differently. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If someone can run the first code on top and tell me if it works for them or not, that would be big help also. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot create the foreign key constraint before you create the table.  Create `Doctors` and `Owners` before `Patients`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of creating Patients table, owner and Doctor table information is not available. So it is not allowing you.

So just create the table first. 
and then add FK with alter table.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding you tables in the wrong order.

You create the Patients table with foreign key constraints before you create the tables/fields they rely on to exist.